# How to find a pixel using a previously found pixel index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have a point 'A' in a matrix, and i have been able to search for a particular pixel value (say ‘30’) around the 8-connected neighborhood of 'A' (with value ‘00’).
The 'find' function returns an index (say of '1') of that pixel value of interest around point 'A'.

Now the issue is that i need to find exactly another pixel (of the same value) which is connected to the initial pixel value of ‘30’ using the returned index information from the 1st search. The 2nd pixel value of ‘30’ is not in the immediate neighborhood of ‘A’ but in it’s next immediate neighborhood.

The code so far:

```
img = [20 20 20 20 20 20 20;
       20 30 20 20 20 20 20;
       20 20 30 20 20 20 20;
       40 40 10 00 20 20 20;
       40 40 10 40 40 40 40;
       40 10 10 40 40 40 40;
       10 10 10 40 40 40 40] 

[Arow, Acol]     = find(img==00)
AIdx             = sub2ind(size(img), Arow, Acol);
M                = size(img, 1);
neighbor_offsets = [-M-1, -M, -M+1, -1, 1, M-1, M, M+1];

%Compute index array of the immediate neighbors of ‘A’
Aneighbors       = bsxfun(@plus, AIdx, neighbor_offsets);

%search for pixel value of ‘30’ in the immediate neighbors of ‘A’
find(img(Aneighbors)==30)
```

the last line of the code returns an index of 1. Is it possible to use this information to find the other 30?

I know I can easily find this 2nd pixel value by creating another index array of the next immediate neighbours of ‘A’ (where the 2nd ‘30’ resides) as follows:

```
    neigh_Aneighbor_offsets = [(-2*M)-2, (-2*M)-1, (-2*M), (-2*M)+1,(-2*M)+2, -M-2, -M+2, -2, 2, M-2, M+2, (2*M)-2, (2*M)-1, (2*M), (2*M)+1, (2*M)+2];

%Compute index array of the 2nd immediate neighbors of ‘A’
neigh_Aneighbors        = bsxfun(@plus, Aidx, neigh_Aneighbor_offsets);

%Search for the 2nd pixel value of ‘30’ in the next immediate neighborhood of ‘A’
find(img(neigh_Aneighbors)==30)
```

However, I would only want to find this by assuming that I know nothing else except the location of the 1st ‘30’ that I have already found.
In any case, I have no idea how to go about this. Any help/suggestion/advice is duly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to search in the 8-connected neighborhood of the first result? i.e. if the 2nd '30' were located at (2,5), would you still want to find it? Also I think you want `find(img(Aneighbors)==30)` rather than `find(img(Aneighbors==30))`.

Comment: Yes! i would want to find all possible 30's in the 2nd neighborhood of the center 00, plus you're right about "find(img(Aneighbors)==30)". some oversight i guess. Thank you.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're trying to do. What you just described is not quite the same as finding "another pixel ... connected to the initial pixel value of '30'". What you called "the 2nd neighborhood of the center 00" doesn't depend on the location of the 1st '30'.

Comment: My bad! you can imagine so many permutations in my head at this point. Pixel location of (2,5) isn't connected to the one at (3,3), hence my response to your question should have been a "No". I only need to find all possible 30's connected to the 1st one found at (3,3), which is the main reason why I do not want to use the 2nd neighbourhood "neigh_Aneighbors". Hope it is clearer now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save result of `find` to a variable `f` and obtain proper `Aidx` from `Aneighbors(f)`:

```
f=find(img(Aneighbors)==30)
Aidx = Aneighbors(f)
Aneighbors=bsxfun(@plus, Aidx, neighbor_offsets)
f=find(img(Aneighbors)==30)
```